# reading data compressed by NSMutableData using the lz4 library in python

Tags: python, swift, lz4, nsmutabledata

I'm compressing random data using NSMutableData (in Swift) as follows:

```swift
import Foundation

let n = 1024
let numbers = (0..<n).map { _ in UInt8.random(in: 0...1) }

print("generated random data: \(numbers)")

let data = Data(numbers)
let mutable = NSMutableData(data: data)
try! mutable.compress(using: .lz4)

print("compressed size: \(mutable.count)")'

try! mutable.write(toFile: "compressed.dat", options: [])
```

And reading into python using:

```py
import os
import lz4.frame

fh = open('compressed.dat', 'rb')
ba = bytearray(fh.read())

print("read %d bytes" % len(ba))

decompressed = lz4.frame.decompress(ba)

print("decompressed to %d bytes" % len(decompressed))
```

When calling `lz4.frame.decompress`, I get:

```
RuntimeError: LZ4F_getFrameInfo failed with code: ERROR_frameType_unknown
```

trying `lz4.block.decompress`, I get:

```
_block.LZ4BlockError: Decompression failed: corrupt input or insufficient space in destination buffer. Error code: 4
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I had a look into this starting with confirming I could decompress the stream back in to a Data in Swift. I don't think you're doing anything wrong, I think the Apple implementation of LZ4 differs from Python. The Apple docs https://developer.apple.com/documentation/compression/algorithm/lz4 for their LZ4 implementation mentions the addition of 'a very simple frame to the raw stream to allow some additional validation and functionality', additionally the LZ4 homepage lists interoperable ports that include Python, but not Apple https://lz4.github.io/lz4/ Hope you find a simple solution to this

Comment: Forget about using Apple data compression. There is many pods out there that would probably work. Try this one https://github.com/marmelroy/Zip

Comment: Hi! Did you find a way to do this?